# Shields.io badges not displaying releases or logo for correct user and repo

Tags: github, badge, readme, shields.io

I'm currently working on creating badges using [Shields](https://shields.io), and I have made sure to provide the correct user and repository names. Additionally, I have included the correct logo code obtained from [simpleicons](https://simpleicons.org). However, when I generate the badge, it displays the message '**no releases**' and does not show the logo.

[image: Shields.io]

What does the 'no releases' message mean, and how can I resolve this issue? I have double-checked that the repository has releases, so I'm not sure why this message is being displayed. Furthermore, I would like to know why the logo is not showing up on the badge.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this problem. Thank you in advance!

I tried generating Shields.io badges using a different person's repository and username. In their case, the badges worked fine, and the logo was displayed correctly. However, when I used my own account's repository and username, instead of seeing the "no releases" message, I saw 'no releases'.
What I expected was for the badge to display the correct release information or show the logo as it did for the other person's repository.[image: working_shields.io]